# Methods returns unexpected results while invokes from timer

Tags: c#, timer

In my application, I have one timer which invoke a method based on 1 second interval.

In that method, I will read one row from table, if that table contains expected records, then I will do some operations.

```
DataTable dtStationCode = new DataTable();
           string LocalStationCode = "";
           try
           {
               oDataParamBLL = new DataParametersBLL();
               oDataParamBLL.Mode = "SELECT_STATIONCODE";
               oDataParamBLL.LineCode = Global.LineCode;
               oDataParamBLL.OperationCode = Global.OperationCode;
               dtStationCode = oServerperformBLL.GetStationCode(oDataParamBLL);
               if (dtStationCode != null)
               {
                   if (dtStationCode.Rows.Count > 0)
                   {
                       foreach (DataRow dr in dtStationCode.Rows)
                       {
                           log.Info("Data Table Row Value Station Code : "+dr[0].ToString());
                       }
                       LocalStationCode = dtStationCode.Rows[0]["StationCode"].ToString();
                       dtStationCode = null;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       log.Fatal("Station Code not Available on Assy_Stations_Jig_In_Out_Status Table");
                   }
               }
```

but when I try to read data from that table, some times I got an exception

```
"Column StationCode does not belong to the table"
```

But I'm getting the exception some time only, If I restart the application it is working fine. After sometime same exception is coming.

I'm suspecting my timer is behaving something wrong.please suggest if anything wrong.

My Timer Event:

```
timerToMonitorExcel = new System.Timers.Timer();
timerToMonitorExcel.Enabled = true;
timerToMonitorExcel.Start();
log.Info("Timer Started");
timerToMonitorExcel.Interval = 1000;
timerToMonitorExcel.Elapsed +=new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timerToMonitorExcel_Elapsed);



static object LocktimerToMonitorExcel_Elapsed = new object();
      Dictionary<string, string> dictParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      void timerToMonitorExcel_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
      {
          Monitor.Enter(LocktimerToMonitorExcel_Elapsed);
          try
          {
              GetJigStatus();

          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              log.Error("Issue on Excel Data ", ex);
          }
          finally
          {

              Monitor.Exit(LocktimerToMonitorExcel_Elapsed);
          }
      }
```

Comment: Did you try to profile your application?

Comment: what do you mean profile ? you means log?

Comment: I didn't see in the code where the error message is coming from.  When you have a timer you have to make sure when the timer event is changing data that you prevent the main code from accessing the data by locking the data.  The timer event is running asynchronously from the main code.  So lock the data as shown on following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: I have a try catch block ,    LocalStationCode = dtStationCode.Rows[0]["StationCode"].ToString(); from this line  i m getting the exception.

Comment: GetJigStatus(); this method will call the piece of code at very first. Also,I have used https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I expect this call `oServerperformBLL.GetStationCode(oDataParamBLL);` to be the issue. You expect it to return a table with that column, but it doesn't. As I don't see you instantiate `oServerperformBLL` anywhere I suspect it to be shared on multiple threads and that is causing a race condition. There is nothing wrong with the code you show.

Comment: @rene but if i use lock statement for all methods which accessed by timer event. does it make a deadlock or something? Should i have to use lock in methods,because I have one timer then why should i have to use lock statement.